# how do i install mariadb on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mariadb, ubuntu-16.04

i have been trying to install mariadb on my ubuntu machine but the error ii keep getting is shown on the link below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPhuF.jpg  "Error Image"

tried uninstalling mysql and mariadb nd reinstalled  mariadb all over again

apt-get install mariadb-server

my expected result is below when i try to check the status after installation

mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.10 database server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
└─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
Active: active (running) 
Docs: man:mysqld(8)
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
Main PID: 15152 (mysqld)
Status: "Taking your SQL requests now..."
CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
└─15152 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it would be better served on Ask Ubuntu

Comment: dba.stackexchange.com is possible a better site.